Manga where girl goes back into time to save her boyfriend
I'm looking for a manga where this girl goes back in time to save her boyfriend. I forgot if it was set in a historical fantasy setting or a more modern setting.
All I remember is that the plot twist was that it wasn’t their second life and that she originally died first and the boyfriend regressed to save her and it just kept repeating back and forth of them trying to save each other (it’s like their 4th or 5th life now)
It’s not “Return From Death: I Kicked the Bucket and Now I'm Back at Square One With a Boyfriend Who Doesn't Remember Me”. I think I remember one of their deaths was that they took a different road than usual and one of them got hit by a car??

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

i think it was black and white since it was a manga

Are there any other details you can recall? Finding a story based on a plot twist is difficult as it won't show up in summaries.

"I will not get involved with Ichijou Kaname!" has the twist that the boyfriend also went back in time, but not the repeated time travel. As far as I can tell each only went back in time once.

This may be Back to You, aka Just a Girl He Knows.

What if an unexpected accident suddenly transported you back to ten years ago? For Hayoung, suddenly traveling back in time to high school means the opportunity to save the life of Jaehyun, the one person she's always loved... Will she be able to change both of their fates?

The car accident could be a bus accident that leads to the death of Jaehyun, the protagonist's crush.

This other answer states that Jaehyun is also involved in time travel. I suspect this happens in the middle of the story and I wasn't able to find any other details on it, including whether or not this is a repeated thing. Him getting on the bus when he "can't ride the bus when it's raining" and the repeated mentions of fate would suggest that he was acting out of character due to his own time travel.
